# Automatically fitting distribution to histogram in Matlab or Java

Tags: java, matlab, statistics, histogram, distribution

I have a histogram plot of one feature (machine learning). That mean on the x-axis I have several value the feature can take and on the y-axis I have the number of occurences.

Is it possible in Matlab (or Java) to automatically fit a probability distribution to this histogram if I don't know which type of distribution it is (normal distribution or geometric distribution etc.)? That means Matlab (or Java) should figure out which distribution it is and give me the optimal parameters.

The problem is that I have a lot of features and manually inspecting the features takes too much time.

Edit: I have found the following Matlab tool which does the job: http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2012/02/10/finding-the-best/ Unfortunately it supports only parametric models.

Edit2: I'm now a bit confused. I have read that I have to normalize my histogram so that I see empirical probabilities instead of the numbers. Is this true if I want to try all possible parametric distribution and pick the best one? How can this normalization be done in Matlab?

Comment: Without any sort of training + modelling, your best bet is to brute force every distribution onto the data and calculate the RMSE (or other means of telling how well the distribution fit your data) and choose the one with the lowest RMSE, but this is far from ideal and can easily cause errors.

Comment: @GameOfThrows I have updated my question.

Comment: If you aren't interested in parametric models, then you need to add a lot more explanation to your question.  Why do you think parametric models are insufficient?  If you aren't interested in parametric models, why aren't you just using the empirical distribution?  What criteria for fitting are you interested in using?  Why are you doing this fitting? What do you hope to accomplish by this fitting?  You're dropping a lot of context (which is fine), but when the answer to your stated question (allfitdist) isn't good enough, you need to state more.

Comment: The link you've posted in Edit 1 is exactly what I am talking about, if you read the file description here http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34943-fit-all-valid-parametric-probability-distributions-to-data This toolbox basically uses a number of distributions to try and fit your data. Each time calculating the RMSE and decide the best fit at the very end. You do not actually need to complicate things. First, what distributions do you want to try? Normal, linear, quadratic etc? You only need to write a loop with IF conditions to do this. Trust me, it is EASY.

Comment: Also to answer your EDIT 2, normalizing your data into PDF does not change your fitting and yes it changes your RMSE calculation. So you either normalize every one of them or you don't normalize anything. Normalization is a good practice when you are comparing each histogram, but does not affect your curve fitting.

Comment: @GameOfThrows Thanks for the useful explanations. Just a last small question: If I would like to create a histogram of values (that means the empirical distribution), how should I choose the bin width?

Comment: There are many methods to this, I refer you on to this Stack Exchange answer: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/798/calculating-optimal-number-of-bins-in-a-histogram-for-n-where-n-ranges-from-30 There are many ways to do it, and there isn't a strict rule, too few bins will lose resolution, causing your hist to miss critical data, too many bins is more data to store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know of any tool that automatically finds the best type of distribution. But, as real data do usually not correspond to one distribution exactly and there is an arbitrary amount of possible distributions, it would also make little sense for such a tool to exist.

I would recommend to limit your questions to certain distribution models (Gaussian, symmetric,...), compute a best fit for the respective model, generate a likelyhood parameter for each fit and then take the fit/model with the highest likelyhood.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see my second edit in the original post.

Comment: A normalization means that the overall probability of the histogram is 1.
To do this in matlab for a vetcor "data", you can just use:
 data = data./sum(data);
so that sum(data) = 1;